# How should I allow a FileField not need to upload a new file when the existed in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model like this:

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
    content = models.FileField(upload_to='xxx')
    other_val = models.CharField(...)  # not important
```

And a form wrapping this model (ModelForm):

```
class AssignmentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Assignment
        fields = ['content', 'other_val']
```

My view looks like this (for simplicity I skip the request.POST/request.FILES. part):

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def create_assignment(request):
    form = AssignmentForm()
    # render form

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def update_assignment(request, assignment_id):
    assignment = Assignment.objects.get(id=assignment_id)
    form = AssignmentForm(instance=assignment)
```

Creating an assignment works just fine - It forces me to upload a file, which is what I want. But when I want to update the content of the assignment (the file), it first shows a link of a previously uploaded file (excellent!) then the upload button, like this:

```
Currently: AssignmentTask_grading_script/grading_script_firing.py 
Change: [Choose File] no file chosen
```

But then I assume if I don't want to replace this file, I should simply click the submit button. Unfortunately, when I click the submit button, the form complains that I should upload a file. Is there a way to silent the complaint if a file is already in database?

Comment: Default django form in the template `{{ form.content }}` it showed it... I just don't know why it doesn't exist for u... But, if you want show the current existed value, you can do with `{{ form.content.value }}`...

Comment: @SancaKembang, thanks for your reply, but I'm asking is there a way to skip the file selection check, which is handled by django I believe. I'm not going to manipulate what it shows on template, though

Comment: In the form, you need to add the file field that has `required=False` to make it optional.

Comment: @Rohan, I want to force a user to upload a file when she creates her assignment, but she can optionally replace the file when updating the assignment. It's more like, when creating an assignment, I want `required=True`, and when updating, `required=False`. Is there an existing widget which can fulfill my requirement?

Comment: perhaps can handle it with javascript... I'll show it if you want...

Comment: @SancaKembang, that would be cool!

Comment: You can create 2 separate forms for create and update views.

Answer (score 1):

As following the previous comments, maybe like this;

**1. `forms.py`**

```
class AssignmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # as following @Rohan, to make it optional.
    content = forms.FileField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Assignment
        fields = ['content', 'other_val']
```

**2. `yourtemplate.html`**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=".">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>

<script> 
{% if not form.content.value %}
  $('#id_content').attr({'required': 'required'});
{% endif %}
</script>
```

> The field of `content` is under required only if havn't value before...